# how to initialize and fill list of lists in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need to have a list of lists like mentioned below :-

```
some_name = [(statement, sentiment),
             (statement, sentiment),
             ...
             ...
             ...
            ]
```

accessing them is fine, but how to fill them up with two different lists namely statement and sentiment.

Comment: use the `zip` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
some_name = [(statement, sentiment) for statement, sentiment
             in zip(statements_list, sentiment_list)]
```

**EDIT** In Python 2 you don't need to iterate over the return value of `zip`, so this will suffice:

```
some_name = zip(statements_list, sentiment_list)
```